# Fatal error when using some filters or sorting options in admin/content

Tags: views, 8

Using Drupal 8.8.0, multilingual, on localhost (Windows 10, PHP 7.3.12).

I have a fatal error on the `admin/content` page, but only if I use certain options for sorting or filtering the results.

Available filters:

- title: works fine
- content type: **fatal error**
- published status: works fine
- language: works fine

Available sorting options:

- title: **fatal error**
- content type: **fatal error**
- author: **fatal error**
- status (published/not): works fine
- updated: works fine
- created: works fine

However if a filter is in use (and hasn't caused a crash), then all sorting options work fine, as far as I can tell.

When checking the server log, I find the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\Entity\\EntityViewDisplay.php on line 258 #0 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Entity\\Render\\EntityFieldRenderer.php(276): Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\Entity\\EntityViewDisplay->buildMultiple(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#1 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Entity\\Render\\EntityFieldRenderer.php(163): Drupal\\views\\Entity\\Render\\EntityFieldRenderer->buildFields(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#2 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\field\\EntityField.php(846): Drupal\\views\\Entity\\Render\\EntityFieldRenderer->render(Object(Drupal\\views\\ResultRow), Object(Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\field\\EntityField)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#3 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\field\\FieldPluginBase.php(1148): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\field\\EntityField->getItems(Object(Drupal\\views\\ResultRow)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#4 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\views.theme.inc(236): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\field\\FieldPluginBase->advancedRender(Object(Drupal\\views\\ResultRow)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#5 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Theme\\ThemeManager.php(287): template_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_fiel...', Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#6 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(431): Drupal\\Core\\Theme\\ThemeManager->render('views_view_fiel...', Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#7 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(200): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doRender(Array, false), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#8 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\field\\FieldPluginBase.php(1747): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->render(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#9 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase.php(770): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\field\\FieldPluginBase->theme(Object(Drupal\\views\\ResultRow)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#10 [internal function]: Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase->elementPreRenderRow(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#11 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Security\\DoTrustedCallbackTrait.php(100): call_user_func_array(Array, Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#12 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(781): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_ren...', 'silenced_deprec...', 'Drupal\\\\Core\\\\Ren...'), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#13 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(372): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#14 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(200): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doRender(Array, false), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#15 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase.php(709): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->render(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#16 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase.php(576): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase->renderFields(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#17 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase.php(468): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase->renderGrouping(Array, Array, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#18 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\display\\DisplayPluginBase.php(2140): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\style\\StylePluginBase->render(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#19 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\ViewExecutable.php(1533): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\display\\DisplayPluginBase->render(), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#20 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Plugin\\views\\display\\Page.php(183): Drupal\\views\\ViewExecutable->render(), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#21 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\ViewExecutable.php(1630): Drupal\\views\\Plugin\\views\\display\\Page->execute(), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#22 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\views\\src\\Element\\View.php(77): Drupal\\views\\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#23 [internal function]: Drupal\\views\\Element\\View::preRenderViewElement(Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#24 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Security\\DoTrustedCallbackTrait.php(100): call_user_func_array(Array, Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#25 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(781): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_ren...', 'silenced_deprec...', 'Drupal\\\\Core\\\\Ren...'), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#26 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(372): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#27 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(200): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->doRender(Array, false), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#28 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer.php(226): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->render(Array, false), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#29 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer.php(573): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\{closure}(), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#30 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer.php(227): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\\Core\\Render\\RenderContext), Object(Closure)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#31 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer.php(117): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), Object(Drupal\\Core\\Routing\\CurrentRouteMatch)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#32 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\EventSubscriber\\MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\\Core\\Render\\MainContent\\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), Object(Drupal\\Core\\Routing\\CurrentRouteMatch)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#33 [internal function]: Drupal\\Core\\EventSubscriber\\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#34 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#35 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\HttpKernel.php(156): Drupal\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent)), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#36 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#37 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\Session.php(57): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#38 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#39 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\page_cache\\src\\StackMiddleware\\PageCache.php(106): Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#40 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\modules\\page_cache\\src\\StackMiddleware\\PageCache.php(85): Drupal\\page_cache\\StackMiddleware\\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#41 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\\page_cache\\StackMiddleware\\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#42 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#43 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\vendor\\stack\\builder\\src\\Stack\\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\\Core\\StackMiddleware\\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true), referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content
#44 C:\\htdocs\\myproject\\www\\core\\lib\\Drupal\\Core\\DrupalKernel.php(694): Stack\\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, tru, referer: http://localhost/myproject/www/fr/admin/content

(Every line starting with [Fri Dec 06 19:26:08.993106 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16812:tid 1200] [client ::1:64229] mod_fcgid: stderr:)
```

Can anybody help identify what is causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar error on another (custom) views page and it helped me understand the cause of this error. This time, the full error was:

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults() (line 223 of C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder.php) #0 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\node\src\NodeViewBuilder.php(61): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node), 'teaser')
#1 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder.php(168): Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node), 'teaser')
#2 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder.php(134): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->viewMultiple(Array, 'teaser', 'es')
#3 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\Entity\Render\TranslationLanguageRenderer.php(90): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->view(Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node), 'teaser', 'es')
#4 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\row\EntityRow.php(247): Drupal\views\Entity\Render\TranslationLanguageRenderer->preRender(Array)
#5 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase.php(434): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\row\EntityRow->preRender(Array)
#6 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\ViewExecutable.php(1508): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->preRender(Array)
#7 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\display\Page.php(183): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render()
#8 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\ViewExecutable.php(1630): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page->execute()
#9 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\views\src\Element\View.php(77): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_2', Array)
#10 [internal function]: Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
#11 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Security\DoTrustedCallbackTrait.php(100): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(781): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_ren...', 'silenced_deprec...', 'Drupal\\Core\\Ren...')
#13 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(372): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array)
#14 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(200): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#15 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer.php(226): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, false)
#16 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
#17 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer.php(227): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer.php(117): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#19 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#20 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#21 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#22 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(156): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
#23 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#24 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#26 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\page_cache\src\StackMiddleware\PageCache.php(191): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#27 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\page_cache\src\StackMiddleware\PageCache.php(128): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#28 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\modules\page_cache\src\StackMiddleware\PageCache.php(82): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#29 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#30 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#31 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#32 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(694): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#33 C:\htdocs\myproject\www\index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#34 {main}.
```

The part that caught my eye is on line #2: `viewMultiple(Array, 'teaser', 'es')`

Like I said, this is a multilingual site (it's actually an old D6 site that I'm currently migrating to D8). It used to have 5 languages for content, but at some point the client decided to drop 2 of those languages (Spanish and Italian). But there are still content entries for those languages in the Drupal database.

Up to this point, Drupal was still configured to use the 5 initial languages, but I recently decided to remove the two unused languages in order to simplify the UX. That's where the error started to appear (although I did not run into it immediately).

So in short, **a view trying to display pieces of content in a language that is no longer present in Drupal will cause this error.**

I added Spanish and Italian back in Drupal, and after that the error stopped occurring. I then deleted all contents in Italian and Spanish, then removed those languages from Drupal again: the error hasn't come back.

Problem solved as far as I can tell.